# I am trying to install npm package called "bcrypt"

Tags: python, node.js, npm, bcrypt

I am fairly new to coding and I would like to receive your help, seniors. 
How can I install "bcrypt" package. I am getting the same error over and over again. 
It required me to install latest version of python so that I installed python-3.8.2 version.
It gave me the same error as it did before. 
I tried `$ npm install bcrypt@3.0.6` as well.
A piece of the error message I am constantly getting is the following.

```
$ npm install bcrypt

> bcrypt@4.0.1 install C:\Users\Turuu\node_modules\bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@4.0.1 and node@12.16.3 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error Remote end closed socket abruptly.
gyp ERR! find Python 
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
```

I feel like I need to require python in my app.js or install some other python packages?
I am very confused.

Comment: If you have python installed follow the directions, otherwise install python and then follow them

Comment: You need to install python(any version) and check the system environment for the python path is configured, before you install this npm package.

Comment: where you ran your npm install command try running "python" If this doesn't work your python path isn't setup.

Comment: as noted, you need python 2 or python 3 installed *and in your path*.  Sounds like you haven't done the 2nd part.  Python is an install-time dependency for node-gyp built NPM modules.

Comment: It's been so long time, sorry. I installed different package and it worked without no python.